# close paper-dialog or paper-action-dialog with javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer

in my use case i have a paper-action-dialog that i use as a first run dialog so i can get server connection info from the user. i am using  autoclosedisabled attribute cause i do not want the user to click off the dialog and close before i get the server details. when the user submits the details i would like the dialog to stay open until i get a return from the server telling the app the details are valid. then i would like to close the dialog with javascript and do the ajax call for data.

html

```
<paper-action-dialog id="firstRun" autoclosedisabled transition="core-transition-center">
  <custom-form></custom-form>
</paper-action-dialog>
```

currently i am using `document.querySelector('core-overlay-layer').classList.remove('core-opened');` it does close the dialog but it looks like that causes issues with any dialog you try to open after as well as causing issues with toasts. then you have to reload the app to correct the issues.

is there anyway to close a paper-dialog or paper-action-dialog with javascript?

i really am not a big fan of the idea of closing the dialog when the user clicks submit just to open again if for any reason the submission fails.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just call close method like this.$.firstRun.close()

An example: https://github.com/Kalitte/polymer-router-demo/

Comment: great thanks. i couldn't access with document.querySelector("#firstRun") and i didn't see anything about this method in the documentation for paper-dialog or action-dialog.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually you can also use this.querySelector('paper-action-dialog') also if you don't set an id.

Comment: i couldn't find this method in paper-dialog documentation cause it isn't there. this info is in core-overlay documentation which paper-dialog extends. just leaving this here for anyone else looking for where to find this in docs.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you can used the "opened" attribute on the  tag:

```
<paper-action-dialog opened="{{dialogOpen}}"></paper-action-dialog>
```

then inside any of your Polymer function calls in your js, just say:

```
foo: function(){
   this.dialogOpen = true;
}
```

I like this method because to me it seems more "Polymerish" as it involves using attributes. Whatever works though.

Additionally, another way similar to a previous answer is to use Polymers magical $ stuff in any of your functions:

```
this.$.firstRun.toggle();
```

You can use this.$.id to access any polymer elements and their methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .toggle() method of the element.
You can access the element after polymer-ready event

```
var el = document.getElementById('yourdialogid');
el.toggle()
```

Comment: I did try toggle() but couldn't access the element with querySelector or getElementById once it was open.  Once the element is open it is inside the shadowdom of core-overlay.